# Difference between printing out pointer vs dereferenced pointer

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between this:

```
int num = 5;
int* num1 = &num;
printf("%p", num1);
```

and this:

```
int num = 5;
int* num1 = &num;
printf("%p", &num1);
```

Comment: If `num` is your friend, `&num` tells you where your friend lives, `num1` is a note saying where your friend lives, and `&num1` tells you where you put the note that says where your friend lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `printf("%p", num1);`, you're printing the value of `num1`, which is the address of `num`.

In the second case, `printf("%p", &num1);`, you're printing the address of `num1`.

Answer (score 3):

The first piece of code prints the *contents* of `num1`, which contains the address of `num`.  The second piece prints the *address* of `num1` itself.

Both are printing an address, each of two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `%p` printf format specifier expects an argument compatible with `void *`, so you should cast the corresponding arguments if necessary.

For the first case:

```
int num = 5;
int* num1 = &num;
printf("%p", (void *)num1);
```

The address of the `num` variable is printed, since `num1` points to `num`.

For the second case:

```
int num = 5;
int* num1 = &num;
printf("%p", (void *)&num1);
```

The address of the `num1` variable is printed.